# How do I configure an Apple Magic Trackpad to use with Unity?

Tags: unity, 11.04, multi-touch, magic-trackpad

Looking for some detailed document describing configuring Apple Magic Trackpad with multitouch gestures. Currently, Unity runs with single finger tap as left click, 2 fingers tap as right click , 3 fingers tap  as move window.

How do I get right click and drag [for firefox mouse gesture addon needs it] ?.
How do I get middle click ?
Is there way to configure 4 fingers and all other options. Any pointer would help a lot.

Thanks.

Comment: touchegg seems to be having all options configurable. however its not yet ready for 11.04. i tried it and didnt have successful run yet.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/touchegg/issues/detail?id=51&can=1&q=11.04 . I tried it, It works. However, its not ready fully as per developer note. Once touchegg ready, and with unity will rock.!!.

Answer (score 3):

I have got the Apple Magic Trackpad too and of course, I have to admit that it works better on Mac OS X. Thanks to [OMG!Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/03/multi-touch-gesture-creator-touchgg-hits-version-2-adds-gestures-actions-gui) I discovered [Touchegg](https://github.com/JoseExposito/touchegg) a very nice app that gives us many options for increase usability. Give it a try!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Although the article in the link refers to the Magic Trackpad being used in ubuntu 10.10, hopefully it will give you an insight on how to make full use of it.

[OMG! Ubuntu! Apple Magic Trackpad Article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/09/benjamin-gets-his-hands-on-the-apple-magic-trackpad/)