# Magic Trackpad 2 is not recognized as synpatic touchpad

Tags: mouse, touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics, magic-trackpad

I have found a lot of posts on the Internet working with Apple Magic Trackpad on Ubuntu. I bought Apple Magic Trackpad 2 and seems like it is not recognized as a touchpad. I can do left click and cursor movements, but nothing else (not scrolling, no two-finger click, ...). Any ideas on how I can make it work?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the output of the command `xinput`

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to emulate a Synaptic Touchpad input with an Apple Magic Trackpad, but if you are just looking to make use of the features of the trackpad, you may want to look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34417/how-do-i-configure-an-apple-magic-trackpad-to-use-with-unity)

Comment: As I understood, Magic Trackpad 1 is working relatively fine on Ubuntu, at least, basic features as two-/three-finger clicks and scrolling are working. And the story with Magic Trackpad 2 is very different it is not recognized as a touchpad at all.

Comment: Relevant Kernel Bug: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=112481 - https://github.com/tiziano88/magic-trackpad-2-linux seems to be tracking progress on attempting to get this device to work, in the issues of that repo is a link to (maybe) working kernel patches

Comment: Still wondering if this is possible with 16.04

Answer (score 0):

There is a driver available for the **Apple Magic Trackpad 2** on [Github](https://github.com/robotrovsky/Linux-Magic-Trackpad-2-Driver). Highlights from the `README.md` file:

- `robbi5` created a `dkms` package with the driver that is known to work with `kernel 4.4.0-57-generic` on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- Used this driver in combination with the mtrack-driver, to make use of the multitouch feature (e.g. 2-finger-tap for right-click, etc)
- Right now the driver only works over USB. OP has submitted an official patch to `linux-input`.